# How do I target a div without a class or id but with all these specific style-attributes

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I'm restyling a certain page where I don't have access to all the source-HTML. So I'm left over with some hard to target elements within a page I need removed.

For example the page is swamped with `<div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px;"></div>`.

To get rid of them I tried this in CSS:

```
div[style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px;"] { 
  display:none !important;
}
```

I'd like to fix this using CSS, because the the HTML that needs to be removed is updated using ajax.

How do I target a div without a class or id but with all these specific style-attributes?

Some more of the source-code (took a while to organize the parsed source):

```
<div>                       
    <span class="Block BigPhotoList_Block">
        <span class="Photo BigPhotoList_Photo" style="height: 200px">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760187/Le-Coq-Sportif-Angers-Low.html.html">
                <span style="background-image:url(http://61955.static.securearea.eu/Files/2/61000/61955/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/144036303.jpg);" class="Canvas BigPhotoList_Canvas" title="Le-Coq-Sportif-Angers-Low"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Title BigPhotoList_Title">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760187/Le-Coq-Sportif-Angers-Low.html.html">
                Le Coq Sportif Angers Low
                </a>
        </span>     
        <span class="Price BigPhotoList_Price" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 89,95
        </span>
    </span>

    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px; border-right: 1px dashed #A0A0A0;" class="BigPhotoList_Stippel"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px;"></div>

    <span class="Block BigPhotoList_Block">
        <span class="Photo BigPhotoList_Photo" style="height: 200px">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760185/Le-Coq-Sportif-Auveurne-Low.html">
                <span style="background-image:url(http://61955.static.securearea.eu/Files/2/61000/61955/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/144036301.jpg);" class="Canvas BigPhotoList_Canvas" title="Le-Coq-Sportif-Auveurne-Low"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Title BigPhotoList_Title">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760185/Le-Coq-Sportif-Auveurne-Low.html">
                Le Coq Sportif Auveurne Low
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Price BigPhotoList_Price" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 79,95
        </span>
    </span>

    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px; border-right: 1px dashed #A0A0A0;" class="BigPhotoList_Stippel"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px;"></div>

    <span class="Block BigPhotoList_Block">
        <span class="Photo BigPhotoList_Photo" style="height: 200px">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760191/Le-Coq-Sportif-Bordeaux-Low.html">
                <span style="background-image:url(http://61955.static.securearea.eu/Files/2/61000/61955/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/144036307.jpg);" class="Canvas BigPhotoList_Canvas" title="Le-Coq-Sportif-Bordeaux-Low"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Title BigPhotoList_Title">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760191/Le-Coq-Sportif-Bordeaux-Low.html">
                Le Coq Sportif Bordeaux Low
            </a>
        </span>     
        <span class="Price BigPhotoList_Price" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 99,95
        </span>
    </span>

    <span class="Block BigPhotoList_Block">
        <span class="Photo BigPhotoList_Photo" style="height: 200px">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760181/Le-Coq-Sportif-Cannet-Low.html">
                <span style="background-image:url(http://61955.static.securearea.eu/Files/2/61000/61955/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/144036297.jpg);" class="Canvas BigPhotoList_Canvas" title="Le-Coq-Sportif-Cannet-Low"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Title BigPhotoList_Title">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760181/Le-Coq-Sportif-Cannet-Low.html">
                Le Coq Sportif Cannet Low
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Discount BigPhotoList_Discount" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 99,95
        </span>     
        <span class="Price BigPhotoList_Price" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 94,95
        </span>
    </span>

    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px; border-right: 1px dashed #A0A0A0;" class="BigPhotoList_Stippel"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px;"></div>

    <span class="Block BigPhotoList_Block">
        <span class="Photo BigPhotoList_Photo" style="height: 200px">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760183/Le-Coq-Sportif-Rodez-Low.html">
                <span style="background-image:url(http://61955.static.securearea.eu/Files/2/61000/61955/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/144036299.jpg);" class="Canvas BigPhotoList_Canvas" title="Le-Coq-Sportif-Rodez-Low"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Title BigPhotoList_Title">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760183/Le-Coq-Sportif-Rodez-Low.html">
                Le Coq Sportif Rodez Low
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Price BigPhotoList_Price" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 99,95
        </span>
    </span>

    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px; border-right: 1px dashed #A0A0A0;" class="BigPhotoList_Stippel"></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10.25px; height: 284px;"></div>

    <span class="Block BigPhotoList_Block">
        <span class="Photo BigPhotoList_Photo" style="height: 200px">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760189/Le-Coq-Sportif-Sedan-Low.html">
                <span style="background-image:url(http://61955.static.securearea.eu/Files/2/61000/61955/ProductPhotos/MaxContent/144036305.jpg);" class="Canvas BigPhotoList_Canvas" title="Le-Coq-Sportif-Sedan-Low"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Title BigPhotoList_Title">
            <a href="/Webwinkel-Product-83760189/Le-Coq-Sportif-Sedan-Low.html">
                Le Coq Sportif Sedan Low
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="Discount BigPhotoList_Discount" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 109,95
        </span>     
        <span class="Price BigPhotoList_Price" style="font-size: 120%;">
            € 99,95
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can target them via their relation to other more easy to reach elements? What's around them?

Comment: Maybe some of their parents have a id/class? Other than that, it would be highly dependent on the entire html structure.

Comment: Could you please post more of your HTML?

Comment: BTW your code works... http://jsfiddle.net/9n9zt8pu/

Comment: @Totò if you read the question you'll see that that `div` element's `style` gets updated with AJAX.

Comment: What you tried with the style won't work propertly, especially in IE. IE reformats the style attribute (adding or removing spaces), and the CSS selector seems to be sensitive to that. I think @dfsq's suggestion is a better direction to explore.

Comment: But he says that he has all the style attributes. The question is `How do I target a div without a class or id but with all these specific style-attributes?`

Comment: how is AJAX updating those `div` if they dont have `class/id`...i mean how is it targeting those `div`s???

Comment: @NoobEditor It's easy to *add* a div without `id`. Only how to find it afterwards. :)

Comment: I agree with GolezTrol, @dfsq suggestion seems the right one

Comment: I would think reverse and would find a way to add a `class` or `id` for the `div` that is being added/updated by `ajax`. And, even if you find a way to target that `div`, I believe it wouldn't be an optimal solution that works for all the cases. duh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a certain style your `div` element will *always* have, you can use the [`*=` attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) which will match part of the element's `style`:

```css
div[style*="float:"] {
    display: none;
}
```

In this example, if your `div` element *always* has `float:` specified within its `style` attribute, it will match the following results:

```
<div style="float: left;">
<div style="color: #f00; float: left;">
<div style="float: left; background: #f00;">
<div style="color: #f00; float: left; background: #f00;">
```

---

In an ideal world you'd simply give your `div` element an `id` or `class` which you can select upon:

```
<div class="myDiv">
<div id="myDiv">
```

```css
.myDiv, /* or */
#myDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: wont't this be a little risky...might remove all `float:left` `div`s?

Comment: @NoobEditor that entirely depends on OP's markup. Inline style should only ever be set with JavaScript.

Comment: I'd go with something like `[style*="10.25px"]`. Not all elements have a dimension of `10.25px`.

Comment: @HashemQolami if anything I figure that's probably one of the values most likely to be changed through AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I can't just target all divs with a float. @HashemQolami, that did the trick. @JamesDonnely, you could be correct in many cases. Only this certain with gets calculated based on a setting (which in this project will always return the same output: 10.25px) Therefore it is safe to use as selector. I'm able to narrow it down because somewhere up to the root there is a <div> with an Id to use. My solution now is `div#id-to-look-for-children div[style*="10.25px"] { display: none !important; }` If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it as working solution.

Comment: @Ben my answer states that using `float:` here is just an example. You can change that to `10.25px` and my answer still remains the same.

Comment: @Ben IMHO since James pointed out `*=` substring attr selector, my suggestion has no point but targeting a more specific string. Hence in my point of view this could be the answer, specially if James bother himself to update the answer to include `style*="10.25px"` :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided HTML if you want to hide `divs` after `.BigPhotoList_Block` blocks, you can target them like this:

```
.BigPhotoList_Block ~ div[style*="height: 284px;"] {
    display: none;
}
```

It should work [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/rcx4Lygt/).

Read about [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

Comment: somewhat similar solution to @James!! ;)

Comment: Yes. Also this is implementation of my original comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This selector works for that snippet of code

```
 .BigPhotoList_Stippel + div{
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9n9zt8pu/
`+` is called [adjacent sibling comparator](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)